# min-width not working in @keyframe animation in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-animations

Trying to have a div expand on page load:

```
#box {
width: 10px; height: 10px;
-moz-animation:    expandwidth 1s forwards;   
animation:         expandwidth 1s forwards; 
}
```

while the following animation works as expected in firefox:

```
@-moz-keyframes expandwidth{
  100% {width: 60%;  min-width: 800px;}
}
```

this won't quite work in IE 11:

```
@keyframes expandwidth{
  100% {width: 60%;  min-width: 800px;}
}
```

in fact, while it does expand to 60% length, it does not take into account the min-width requirement, which can easily be seen as I shrink the browser size horizontally. In firefox however, it does not shrink under 800px, as intended. Am I doing something wrong? I cannot seem to find anything regarding min-width being unsupported in IE animations. Also note that I am looking for a css fix only. Thanks.

Edit: see http://jsfiddle.net/qyan20k9/ 
works for me in FFX 31.0 but not in IE 11

Comment: Which version of IE are you using so we can reproduce?  Can you do a jsfiddle?

Comment: @moo2u2 The question states IE11.

Comment: Ah you're right, in the middle, sorry I missed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this in IE11, Chrome 38 (64bit)& FF31 and it seems to work is you establish a `min-width` to start with.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qyan20k9/5/)

```
#box {
    width: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    min-width:10px; /* here */
    -moz-animation: expandwidth 1s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: expandwidth 1s forwards;
    animation: expandwidth 1s forwards;
    background: grey;
}
@-webkit-keyframes expandwidth {
    100% {
        width: 60%;
        min-width: 800px;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes expandwidth {
    100% {
        width: 60%;
        min-width: 800px;
    }
}
@keyframes expandwidth {
    100% {
        width: 60%;
        min-width: 800px;
    }
}
```